# How to delete a item in a list of dict with multiple values, If values are same

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, delete-row

## List of machines in 1 database

```
>netbox_list = 
               [{'mac_address': '00:00:00:5B:A4:57', 'device_id': '607', 
              'ip_address': '10.11.2.2'},
               {'mac_address': '00:00:00:5B:A4:51', 'device_id': '608', 
               'ip_address': '10.11.2.3'},
               {'mac_address': '00:00:00:8C:DB:71', 'device_id': '156', 
               'ip_address': '10.11.2.21'}]
```

## List of machine in 2 database

```
>infoblox_list = 
               [{'mac_address': '00:00:00:5B:A4:51', 'ip_address': '10.11.2.3'},
               {'mac_address': ''00:00:00:5B:A4:57', 'ip_address': '10.11.2.2'},
               {'mac_address': ''00:00:00:8C:DB:70', 'ip_address': '10.11.2.20'},
               {'mac_address': ''00:00:00:8C:DB:80', 'ip_address': '10.11.2.22'}]

>netlen = len(netbox_list)
>infolen = len(infoblox_list)
>#difflist = netbox_list

# Objective is to create a list of dict where the 'ip_address' don't match
#Comparing the dicts with values to delete it from the list
>for i in range(netlen):
    for j in range (infolen):
      if netbox_list[i]['ip_address'] == infoblox_list[j]['ip_address']:
        del netbox_list[i]
        break
print(netbox_list)


'''
```

> Error :
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Python/Flask/till now.py", line 53, in 
>           if netbox_list[i]['ip_address'] == infoblox_list[j]['ip_address']:
>       IndexError: list index out of range'''

Comment: Do not modify iterables while you're iterating them. You could iterate a copy though or iterate backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
netbox_list_set = set([x['ip_address'] for x in netbox_list])
infoblox_list_set = set([x['ip_address'] for x in infoblox_list])
unmatched_ips = netbox_list_set - infoblox_list_set
```